# NSDateFormatter dateFromString with date

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i have a problem with method dateFromString, here is my code

```
NSString* res = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",dateInput.text,monthInput.text,yearInput.text];
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy"];
NSDate* inpTime = [formatter dateFromString:res];
[dateResult setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",inpTime]];
```

when I run, the date in "inpTime" always is "dateInput" - 1.
for example: if "dateInput" is 5, the date in "inpTime" will be 4

Comment: Your code is perfect..no error!!!, try cleaning the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the timezone.

Change

```
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
```

to

```
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

This is because you're not setting the time, so it's set by default the midnight UTC.
But when you are displaying the date with a timezone other than UTC the time is shifted accordingly.

As an example if you live in New York the **12/29/2012 00:00:00 UTC** is actually the **12/28/2012 18:00:00** for you.

Comment: thank you, my problem was solve, can you explain why I need to change localTimeZone to timeZoneWithName:@"UTC" :D

Comment: Simply provide it, then set the timezone you want in the `dateFormatter`. Use the same dateFormatter for reading the string and displaying it and you're good, since it will be using the same timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You Code is perfect, no error what so ever.

Try nslogging dateInput.text, monthInput.text and yearInput.text...might be from here you are getting invalid data.